# Installer Dialogue preventing use of Visual Web Developer 2008 Express

Tags: visual-web-developer

Just recently I have found that between five and ten minutes after starting a Visual Web Developer session, a Windows Installer box pops up, saying "Preparing to Install".

This Installer box doesn't appear to do anything, has a cancel button that doesn't cancel, and prevents normal use of the product (only some of the keyboard keys work, one can't activate any menu options, scrolling up and down becomes difficult, and so forth).

I'm using Visual Web Developer 2008 Version 9.0.30729.4462 QFE, with .NET framework 3.5 SP1 running on Windows XP 5.1.2600 SP3.

Does anyone know what is causing this problem and what I can do about it?

**Edit 1**

Several messages along the following lines appear in the Application Event Log:-

```
Event Type: Warning
Event Source:   MsiInstaller
Event Category: None
Event ID:   1004
Date:       17/02/2012
Time:       13:55:46
User:       xxxxxxxxx
Computer:   xxxxxxxxxx
Description: The description for Event ID ( 1004
) in Source ( MsiInstaller ) cannot be found. The local computer may
not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to
display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the
/AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support
for details. The following information is part of the event:
{90120000-0021-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}, ProductFiles,
{0638C49D-BB8B-4CD1-B191-050E8F325736}, C:\Program Files\Common
Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE12\MSO.DLL, (NULL), , .
```

Comment: Anything in the event logs?  Operating system version?

Comment: @DaveM, thanks for the suggestion; there are several likely-looking things in the Event Log: I've added what looks like a typical message to the question. The operating system is Windows XP 5.1.2600 SP3.